# Creating a client from a WSDL file

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, client-server

So I have been trying to do a top-down approach starting with a WSDL. I have been working with free web services located here: http://www.service-repository.com/ I found that I could use the WSIMPORT tool on the WSDL to generate client stubs and invoke the server with the WTP tools offered in eclipse. With a basic hello world file, I have written a main method like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        TempConvert convert = new TempConvert();
        System.out.println(convert.getTempConvertSoap().fahrenheitToCelsius("122"));
    }
}
```

to invoke a converting web service. Now I am moving into more complicated web services like uploading web-services which will except my file. Creating a Main file is becoming difficult as I don't know how to invoke it. Are there any tools that will make you a written client by chance? and if not is there any tips to creating a client for web-services your not familiar with? The reason I ask is because I would like to upload a file every day and will be using Pearl as a bot to time that, but need a client that I Jar and access through the command prompt. Thanks!

Comment: netbeans and eclipse both have built in tools that will take a wsdl and create the client for you.

Comment: Yes, the WTP Web Service Client tool correct? Where it will let you invoke it from a browser with a URL? I'm looking further towards something coded that I can run so that I can jar and access it from the CMD later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Apache CXF as it offers options to generate a JAX-WS Web Service Client from a WSDL document.